# jQuery Datatables pagination setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I'm trying to work with the pagination of the jquery datatables. I load the data with ajax. My response is now:

```
aaData: [[:anonymous:, null, 2012-07-29 08:28:21, 0, 85 million, null],…]
iTotalDisplayRecords: 70
iTotalRecords: 70
sEcho: 1
```

All of my records (70) are shown, how can I make them paginate and have for ex 10 records per page?

I tried settings iTotalDisplayRecords to 10 but it shows the same result.

My datatable init:

```
myDataTable = $('#datatablesresults').dataTable({
    bProcessing  : true,
    sProcessing  : true,
    bServerSide  : true,
    sAjaxSource  : '/results/load-results?' + getParams,
    aoColumnDefs : [{'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : ['no-sort']}], // make the actions column unsortable
    sPaginationType : 'full_numbers',
    fnDrawCallback  : function(oSettings) {
        _initTable();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you find any reason or solution to this problem.I am stuck up with  same problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**try this:**

```
$("#myDataTable").dataTables({
     "bJQueryUI":true,
      "bSort":false,
      "bPaginate":true,
      "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
       "iDisplayLength": 10
});
```

Comment: I have the correct number of pages and I can slide through them, but I still get all my records on every tab. Like this: Showing 21 to 30 of 70 entries, but he shows all 70

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pagingType": "full_numbers"
} );


DataTables has six built-in paging button arrangements:

numbers - Page number buttons only (1.10.8)
simple - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
simple_numbers - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
full - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons
full_numbers - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers
first_last_numbers - 'First' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking simply how to change number of pages displayed in pagination here is code snippet.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.pager.numbers_length = 10;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Basic datatable
  $('#datatable').DataTable();
  .... rest of the code below....
```

You can change number of pages displayed in pagination changing the value '10' in first line.

Comment: Exactly was searching for this info, thank you very much.