# Page navigator at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, .net

I want navigator at the end of the page like: 1 2 3 4 5 6. Clicking on 1 will show some results and then other result will be on other pages numbered 2,3,4,5 and 6. This is just like what Google has at it's bottom.

Is there any component for this in .NET. Else any HTML?

Comment: Its upto your implementation. .net provides default paging in grids but not for pages.

Comment: @ons-jjss what component .net provides for grids?

Comment: What version of .net you are using?

Comment: If using jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422797/jquery-datatables-pagination-setting       try this plug in: http://www.jtable.org/demo/pagingandsorting

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/816953/How-To-Implement-Paging-in-GridView-Control-in-ASP for mvc: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Second link, worked exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its upto your implementation. .Net provides default paging in grids but not for html pages. You can define the paging options depending on type of content. If you simply want to use paging for all your html then you need to map the page # with your html dynamically.

Some good referencs:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/816953/How-To-Implement-Paging-in-GridView-Control-in-ASP

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tables in HTML, you can use this useful DataTables jquery library. Link [here](http://datatables.net/)

Using it is as simple as following example

Ex: `$('#myTable').DataTable( {

    paging: true
} );`